# PHP - Entering data into a database

Tags: php, mysql

I've recently trying to add data into a database, (New to php), I've looked over to see where I've gone wrong, but can't find anything. The error is:

```
Unknown column 'FUMUKU' in 'field list'
```

Code:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'evocityi_admin';
$dbpass = 'password';
$database = 'evocityi_stocks';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $database);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$Dtime = "30/04/16";
$StockName = "FUMUKU";
$FUMUKUPrice = 1000;
$sql = "INSERT INTO stocks".
       "(Stock,Price, TimeD) ".
       "VALUES ".
       "('$StockName,$FUMUKUPrice, $DTime')";
mysql_select_db('evocityi_stocks');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

SQL Database:
https://gyazo.com/fc97b686cfea79ea773d1796e912551e

Comment: Warning! Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks!

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated, it's preferred to use PDO or mysqli_. Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection (if the fields Dtime, StockName or FUMUKUPrice can be altered by the user)

Comment: `$Dtime` not equla to `$DTime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this It will helps you.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO stocks(Stock,Price,TimeD) VALUES ('$StockName','$FUMUKUPrice', '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($Dtime))."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it using:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `stocks` (`Stock`,`Price`, `TimeD`) VALUES ('$StockName','$FUMUKUPrice', '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($Dtime))."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'$StockName,$FUMUKUPrice, $DTime'
```

You should surround every variable with quotes:

```
'$StockName' ,' $FUMUKUPrice' , '$DTime'
```

Just know that when blindly concatenating variables into a SQL query and not preparing statements for user input makes your code vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead. Also, use the `mysqli_*` functions, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, you are not using qoutes properly on the variables due to this It through error.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO stocks".
       "(Stock,Price, TimeD) ".
       "VALUES ".
       "('".$StockName."', '".$FUMUKUPrice."', '".$DTime."')";
```

To avoid deprecation and SQL Injection you should use PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `mysql_*` functions, that's what's wrong.

[Read the documentation](http://php.net/mysql-query) and look into alternatives.

One such alternative may be:

```
$query = $pdoconnection->prepare("
    insert into `stocks`
    (`Stock`,`Price`,`TimeD`)
    values (?,?,?)
");
$query->execute([$StockName, $FUMUKUPrice, $Dtime]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $sql = ("INSERT INTO stocks (Stock,Price, TimeD)
                VALUES('$StockName', '$FUMUKUPrice', '$DTime')");
```